# Comparing Collection Items to List Items to Find Matches

Tags: c#, windows-update

My goal is to take any pending Windows updates that are not explicitly called out in an exception list and dump them into a secondary UpdateCollection of updates that **should** be installed. My pseudo code looks like this:

String list containing KB numbers for updates that shouldn't be installed:

```
List<string> windowsUpdateExceptionKBList
KB1234567
KB2644615
KB483729
```

WUApiLib.UpdateCollection containing update objects

```
UpdateCollection securityUpdatesList
Iupdate object1
Iupdate object2
```

Each update object has a ".Title" property containing the KB number (e.g. Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2644615)). I need something like the following:

```
UpdateCollection securityUpdatestoInstall = new UpdateCollection();

foreach (Iupdate update in securityUpdatesList)
 {  
 foreach (string kB in windowsUpdateExceptionKBList)
    { 
        if (!update.Title **contains** kB)
           {
              securityUpdatestoInstall.Add(update);
           }
    }
 }
```

The above won't work as proposed because it will add duplicate updates to the list due to the nested foreach loops. But I'm having a hard time even conceptualizing how I can accomplish this in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take action if no match was found, so add a variable to track whether a match was found, and break out of the inner `foreach` on the first match, then conditionally add the update depending if a match was found:

```
UpdateCollection securityUpdatestoInstall = new UpdateCollection();

foreach (Iupdate update in securityUpdatesList)
{
    bool blacklisted = false;
    foreach (string kB in windowsUpdateExceptionKBList)
    { 
        if (update.Title.Contains(kB))
           {
              blacklisted = true;
              break;
           }
    }
    if (!blacklisted)
    {
         securityUpdatestoInstall.Add(update);
    }
 }
```

Also note that you can use [string.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so I've added that too (and notice that it's case sensitive).

Comment: That makes sense. Any comment on how I can perform the "contains" operation?

Comment: There's a method for that. I've just added it in.